# Ler e escrever multipas variaves com só um ponteiro

Tags: c, ansi

obtive sucesso em fazer tarefa parecida com o determinado código:

```
int *ptr[5], i;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    ptr[i] = (int *)malloc(1 * sizeof(int));
}

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    scanf("%d", ptr[i]);
}

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);
}
```

No entanto, gostaria de fazer o mesmo com algo similar a isto:

```
int *ptr = (int *)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));
```

Também seria bem vindo a informação do mesmo porem para uma string de caracteres.
Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um vetor alocado dinamicamente se comportará da mesma maneira que um vetor comum.

A referência de um vetor é o seu primeiro elemento, no caso `ptr[0]`, e `ptr` aponta para o primeiro elemento do vetor, e os elementos restantes estarão a uma dada distância do primeiro elemento, por exemplo nesse código o último elemento está a uma distância de "4 ints" do primeiro elemento (`ptr[4]`), por isso a utilização da função `sizeof()`, pois usaremos um "bloco" na memória do tamanho que precisamos nesse caso "5 ints" ou 20 bytes(uma variável do tipo int ocupa 4 bytes).O mesmo caso se aplica aos outros tipos com exceção de uma string, por que uma string é um vetor do tipo char só que nesse caso uma string sempre deve ter como ultimo elemento o caractere`\0`, logo numa alocação dinâmica de n caracteres terá que ser `sizeof(n+1)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
   int *ptr = (int*)malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      scanf("%d", &ptr[i]);
   }

   for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      printf("%d\n", ptr[i]);
   }
   free(ptr);

   return 0;
}
```